# Filesystem which splits large files

Tags: linux, filesystems

I try to use the AmazonCloud-Storage using acd_cli to put my media files into the cloud. Unfortunately acd_cli don't work with large files. 
Therefore I'm search for a (virtual) filesystem which split large files into configurable peaces on the storage side.

E.g. mount.splitfs  
If the user stores a large file into the  the data is only written into  but files exceeding the configured size will be stored as file.{1..n}.

The complete setup will be like:

```
unionfs --+-- local_encfs (RW) ----- local_splitfs ----- local_storage
          |
          +-- acd_encfs (RO) ----- acd_splitfs ----- acd_cli_storage
```

The local and acd path is necesarry as acd_cli only support writing a file in sequence but encfs writes in random positions. 
New files will be written localy and a cron job moves them from the local_storage into the acd_cli_storage if they are older than x days.

I got most of all working but the splitfs is missing. 
Any ideas how the realize the splitfs?

Kind regards, 
Rüdiger

Comment: glusterfs? (Not sure if it can do that, and even if it does I don't know if it's appropriate for your use case)

Answer (score 0):

chunkfs.

> ChunkFS is a FUSE based filesystem that allows you to mount an
>   arbitrary file or block device as a directory tree of files that each
>   represent a chunk of user-specified size of the mounted file.

More info at http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7437/

Comment: Chunkfs devides the complete fs into chunks. The critical size of the amazon cloud drive is 10GiB. I have to store 20TB. This causes the creation of > 2000 chunk files and mount them together. But in the 20TB are much less than this count of files which must be spitt into 2 ore 3 pieces.

Comment: I tested with some localy created files (dd, losetup, mkfs, mount, unionfs) like describet in the referenced articel. Unfortunately I can't create a file larger than one chunk in the union.